# Issue with hair in both viewport and render

Tags: animation, 3d-view, particles, hair

I need to do a render video about some industrial brushes and their function

[image]

But , When I play the viewport animation the bristles start vibrating and then totally detach from the brush itself (you can see it here https://gph.is/g/4zArbRv), and I'm having another issue. Blender crashes when i try to render it.

Does anyone has any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: what are the modifiers on the bristles?

Comment: @SHikhaMittal array with 5 counts on the circle emitting hair, and after that the particle setting.

Comment: oh , then probably i cannot help ;(

Comment: @SHikhaMittal thank you anyway :)

Comment: you might want to add a blend file or explain how the object with the "hair" is modified to attach to the object that is the base rotor.  Is some rigid body involved?

Comment: @james_t no, rigid body is not involved. I've put manually every emitting circle in order to be tangent to the base rotor and all is parented to an empty located in its center.

If you want to check the file, you can find it here: https://we.tl/t-elLjuGK8ZU

Comment: It has something to do with using the Array modifier.  If I remove one of these from a circle with PS, the PS behaves.  And interestingly if I move the Array to be *after* the PS modifier, the PS is not part of the array (only the circle).   You may be able to Duplicate-Linked all of the circles 4 times after they are placed with their PS.  Or blow past my ignorance (I am still learning blender) by posing a new, different question about how to array a PS.   Search "Particle System Array" in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I'll leave to experts to explain, if you Apply the Array modifier on each circle array, the particle system behaves:

[image]

However, if you want each circle array member to behave independently,  you'll have to depart from array and instead Duplicate instead of array.  And if you Dip-linked, the bristles might not behave independently if an effector causes some to deform.

There may be other more expert solutions if you search on "Particle System Array" in this forum.